# Easiest way to see whether these two graphs are isomorphic

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

I've tested a few isomorphic invariants such as total degrees, total vertices, total edges, total amount of degree $4$ vertices and so on.
It seems that it holds for a lot of the isomorphic invariants.
Is there a good efficient way to check in general if two graphs are isomorphic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no efficient way known in general. For these small graphs, you could look at the two vertices of degree $2$. In one graph, they share one neighbor, but in the other they share two.

Comment: Would you please explain in a bit more details